# how to ... Rxjava flowable process on get count

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

i recieve a flowable from a call... now i want to check how many items i recieve and then process based on that. I know from a flowable i can get the single count, but im not sure how i could chain this in Rx way..

The below doesnt work... but im a complete noob to Rx :(

```
  Flowable<Data> dataFlowable = reporter.findData();

  Long count = dataFlowable
      .count()
      .blockingGet();

    if(count > 0) {
     // do something with the flowable returned
        dataFlowable.map(.....);
    }
```

or maybe i can do the following:

```
dataFlowable.toList().map(list -> processList(list));

public void processList(List<Data> list) {

  if(list.size() > 0){
    // do something with list
  }
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to further process received data after count check, you can use filter() after toList():

```
dataFlowable
    .toList() // returns Single<List<Data>>
    .filter(list -> list.size() > 0) // returns Maybe<List<Data>>
    .map(list -> {
        // only called if Maybe contains data (filter condition is true)
        // do something with list
    });
```

Comment: Thanks.. another thing, is it possible to do a blockingGet inside a .map(.. return single.blockingGet..).subscribe(......)

Comment: In RxJava almost every possible usage of `blockingGet` can be expressed via other operators. `.map(.. return single.blockingGet..).subscribe(......)` can be rewritten with [flatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) operator as `.flatMap(smth -> single).subscribe()`